# How to define a particular prefix that can only be used by the owner of the bot?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, prefix, owner

I am trying to set another prefix but only usable by me while keeping the usual prefix for other users.

```
client.on('message', async message => {
  const prefix = '.' 
  if(message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
    const messageArray = message.content.split(' ');
    const cmd = messageArray[0];
    const args = messageArray.slice(1);
    const command = client.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length))
                 || client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)));
    // Command execution
});
```

Comment: You just need to add another condition like: `if(message.content.startsWith(prefix) || (owner && message.content.startsWith(ownerPrefix)) {}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily assign a prefix depending on whether the user is the owner or not by using [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), frequently used as alternative to an [`if...else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement.

If the message author isn't the owner, the prefix will be ​​the default one otherwise it will be the owner prefix:

```js
const prefix = message.author.id !== OWNER_ID ? '.' : OWNER_PREFIX;
```

Both prefixes can be used by the owner but only the default one for users:

```js
const prefix = message.content.startsWith('.') ? '.'
             : message.author.id === OWNER_ID ? OWNER_PREFIX
             : '.';
```